# emacs 24 themes and inherit attribute

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I'm using zenburn from here:

https://github.com/djcb/elisp/blob/master/themes/zenburn-theme.el

It uses a lot of `:inherit` settings.  However, I'm noticing that when I switch to another theme x and then back, x's foreground would remain along with zenburn's `:inherit`.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

:inherit works weirdly in Emacs 24... it is unclear whether the current behavior is a "feature" or bug. I usually load themes with:

```
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(load "zenburn-theme")
```

at the end of my init.el; the explicit load should reset inheritance. [This is the advice given by the author of that theme](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/05/porting-zenburn-theme-to-emacs-24.html), and it works fine for me on other themes as well (such as solarized).

Comment: Hey thanks, that solved an issue I had with my own theme!  Had to re-eval it once Emacs was loaded to correct some colors that should have been set by the theme.  Definitely a bug to me :-)

Comment: I have similar problems with emacs 24. Your solution helped me, but first should be (load... and then (load-theme...

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because Emacs custom themes are *cumulative*, by default. To *replace* one theme by another, it is not enough to *enable* the second one. You must first *disable* the one to be replaced. Otherwise, the effect is to *merge* the two.

Most likely, the loading sequence described by @ChristopherMonsanto has the effect of doing that: disabling the current theme and then enabling the zenburn theme.

FWIW, *color* themes (from library [`color-theme.el`](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme)) work differently from Emacs *custom* themes -- color themes do not have this problem/feature.  See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme for more information.